# Rewrite config file based on standard error output

Tags: python, bash, sed

I'm new to Linux and have a Fedora 20 build for a class.  We installed Tripwire using the default, out of the box configs and I want to take the standard errors from the install to fix the config file.

To collect the errors:

```
tripwire -m i -c tw.cfg 2> errors
```

To clean the error file up for processing:

```
cat errors.txt | grep "/" | cut -d " " -f 3 > fixederrors
```

This gives me a nice clean file with one path per line i.e.:

- /bin/ash
- /bin/ash.static
- /root/.Xresources

I would like to automate this process by comparing the data in fixederrors to the config file and prepend matching strings with a '#'.

I tried sed, but it commented out the whole config file!

```
sed 's/^/#/g' fixederrors > commentederrors
```

Alternatively, I thought about comparing the config file and the fixederrors and creating a third file.  Is there a way to take two files, compare them, and remove duplicated data?

Any help is appreciated.  I tried bash and python, but I don't know enough and went down the rabbit hole on this one.  Again, this is for my growth and not in a production environment.

Comment: `sed 'whatever' fixederrors > commentederrors` why this will change your **config file**? it would work based on your `fixederrors` file, won't it?

Comment: Kent, you're right.  I initially rewrote the config file, but for testing purposes created a new one.

Comment: Show some example: (part of) config file, (part of) fixederrors and expected result.

Comment: @zonmei I don't know what do you want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's we suppose that you have this input file named `fixederrors` *"clean"*

```
/bin/ash  
/bin/ash.static  
/root/.Xresources
```

this input as configuration file named `config.original`

```
use /bin/ash
use /bin/bash
do stuff with /bin/ash.static and friends
/root/.Xresources
do other stuff...
```

With this script in `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
Input_Conf_File="config.original"  # Original configuration file
Output_Conf_File="config.new"      # New configuration file
Input_Error_File="fixederrors"     # File of cleaned error

rm -f $Output_Conf_File            # Let's we create a new file erasing old 
while read -r line ; do            # meanwhile there are line in config file
  AddingChar=""                    # No Char to add # 
  while IFS= read -r line2 ; do    # For each line of Error file, 
    # here you can add specific rules for your match e.g
    # line2=${line2}" "   # if it has always a space after...       
    [[ $line == *$line2* ]] && AddingChar="#"  # If found --> Change prefix "#"
  done < $Input_Error_File
  echo "${AddingChar}${line}" >> $Output_Conf_File # Print in new file
done < $Input_Conf_File
cat  $Output_Conf_File         # You can avoid this it's only to check results 
exit 0
```

You will have this output

```
#use /bin/ash
use /bin/bash
#do stuff with /bin/ash.static and friends
#/root/.Xresources
do other stuff...
```

Note:

- `IFS=` removes trailing spaces in read
- **Use wisely** because e.g. the match  `/bin/ash` will catch lines with  `/bin/ash.EVERYTHING`; so if it exists a line in your configuration input file as **/bin/ash.dynamic** will be commented too. Without prior knowledge of your configuration file it's not possible to set a specific rule, but you can do it starting from here.

Comment: nice, this did just what i needed